# Dokku recognizes my Node.js app as Go app on deploy

Tags: node.js, deployment, web-deployment, docker

I was create Procfile with the contents:

`web: node web.js`

My package.json:

`{
    "name": "app-express",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "description": "web panel",
    "main": "web.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node web.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "async": "^0.2.10",
        ...
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "0.10.x",
        "npm": "1.2.x"
    },
    "keywords": [
        "node"
    ]
}`

When I push my app, I see:

`> git push digitalocean master

Counting objects: 1207, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1141/1141), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1207/1207), 5.43 MiB | 360 KiB/s, done.
Total 1207 (delta 138), reused 0 (delta 0)
-----> Building app-express ...
       Go app detected
remote:  !     A .godir is required. For instructions:
remote:  !     http://mmcgrana.github.io/2012/09/getting-started-with-go-on-heroku
To dokku@95.85.*.*:app-express
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'dokku@95.85.*.*:app-express'`

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dokku uses the [buildstep project](https://github.com/progrium/buildstep) to implement support for Heroku buildpack support. The GO buildpack uses the following detection script:

https://github.com/kr/heroku-buildpack-go/blob/master/bin/detect

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# bin/detect <build-dir>
set -e

if test -n "$(find "$1" -type f -name '*.go' | sed 1q)"
then echo Go
else echo no; exit 1
fi
```

Is there any chance you have files with a ".go" extension in your project's code?

Comment: thanks, had the same issue with my Python app and a simple 'find ./app -type f -name "*.go"' found the cuplrit!